# kafka 0.11 reset offset for consumer group by --to-datetime

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to reset the offset of kafka consumer group by timestamp.
But when I am using following command:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --reset-offsets --to-datetime 2017-11-1907:52:43:00:000 --group <group_name> --topic <topic_name> --execute
```

I am getting the following error message:

> Note: This will only show information about consumers that use the
>   Java consumer API (non-ZooKeeper-based consumers).

how to reset offset according to time

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Invoking

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
--group test-group --reset-offsets --all-topics --to-datetime 2017-08-04T00:00:00.000
```

can resets offsets to the earliest ones after the given datetime. Datetime format is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.xxx`, 2017-08-04T00:00:00.000 for instance.

You could also reset offsets by duration. See an example below:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 
--group test-group --reset-offsets --all-topics --by-duration PT0H30M0S
```

`--by-duration` resets offsets to offset by duration from current timestamp. Format: 'PnDTnHnMnS'.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an error, but just a warning - because you specified `--bootstrap-server` option then changes will affect only consumers that are implemented using new Java API.  If you have consumers that are built using other APIs, then you need to specify `--zookeeper` option instead.

Answer (score 3):

Old thread, but this link is helpful if you want to play with kafka offsets.

https://gist.github.com/marwei/cd40657c481f94ebe273ecc16601674b#file-how_to_reset_kafka_consumer_group_offset-md

Highlight:

> Kafka 0.11.0.0 (Confluent 3.3.0) added support to manipulate offsets
>   for a consumer group via cli `kafka-consumer-groups` command.
>
> 1. List the topics to which the group is subscribed `bash kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <kafkahost:port> --group
>      <group_id> --describe` Note the values under "CURRENT-OFFSET" and
>      "LOG-END-OFFSET". "CURRENT-OFFSET" is the offset where this consumer
>      group is currently at in each of the partitions.
> 2. Reset the consumer offset for a topic (preview) `bash kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <kafkahost:port> --group
>      <group_id> --topic <topic_name> --reset-offsets --to-earliest` This
>      will print the expected result of the reset, but not actually run it.
> 3. Reset the consumer offset for a topic (execute) `bash kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <kafkahost:port> --group
>      <group_id> --topic <topic_name> --reset-offsets --to-earliest
>      --execute` This will execute the reset and reset the consumer group offset for the specified topic back to 0.
> 4. Repeat 1 to check if the reset is successful
>
> #### Note
>
> - The consumer group must have no running instance when performing the reset. Otherwise the reset will be rejected.
> - There are many other resetting options, run `kafka-consumer-groups` for details
>
>   - --shift-by
>   - --to-current
>   - --to-latest
>   - --to-offset
>   - --to-datetime
>   - --by-duration
>
> The command also provides an option to reset offsets for all topics
>   the consumer group subscribes to: `--all-topics`